# Команда импорта данных из одной таблицы в другую postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имею две таблицы c данными:

таблицу 1 - таблица в которую нужно импортировать данные, состоит из множества столбцов

таблица 2 - таблица с данными импорта

Каким кодом можно обновить данные в столбцах ff, re, aw таблицы 1, таблицы сопоставляются по id

Ранее делал через импорт navaicat и таблицы csv, таблица 1 содержит более 10 млн записей и процесс поиска и обновления очень долгий и не автономный, с помощью кода хочу решить проблему автономности.

Comment: А таблицы у вас в одной БД?

Comment: да,обе таблицы в одной БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример обновления:

```
-- Создание таблиц
create table table1(id integer, txt varchar);
create table table2(id integer, txt2 varchar);

-- Наполнение данными
insert into table1 values(1, 'text1');
insert into table1 values(2, 'text2');
insert into table1 values(3, 'text3');

insert into table2 values(1, 'text2');
insert into table2 values(3, 'text2');
-- Обновление
UPDATE table1
SET    txt = txt2
FROM   table2 
WHERE  table1.id = table2.id;
```

Comment: Подскажите, как должен выглядеть запрос если нужно обновить 2-5 колонок, сопоставляя так же по id? Спасибо

Comment: В части `set` перечислите через запятую присваивание